# Django tastypie database update security

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Hi everyone I am new to django tastypie framework and I am trying to make a simple api which has IOS clients.I am trying to implement authorization in such a way that one user can not modify other users data i.e one user can not upload images on behalf of other user.Users should only allowed to make changes to their database records.After surfing from last two days I couldn't able to find any tutorial in implement the same.can anyone let me know the links to do the same.Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [django-guardian](https://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian). And [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/7wonders/6557760) with a custom Authorization class you can use in conjunction with that.

Comment: Thank You.It is very useful